# Do not copy a file which has already been copied

Tags: batch-file, cmd, robocopy

I need to monitor a source directory and copy to a destination directory which another piece of software monitors and then deletes the file when uploaded.

I cannot have this software monitor and upload from the source directory because it must delete the file after the upload completes. The issue with this is some users in my organization do not close the file after they save it to the source directory...there for it cannot be deleted by the software.

So hence why I am copying to another directory and then the software is uploading and deleting from destination dir.

Now all of that works for the most part, however, after robocopy copies the file to the destination directory the software uploads the file and then deletes it, but then robocopy re-copies the same file from the source directory back into the destination directory.

This is a major issue because we can only upload the file once and cannot have duplicates.

I have tried the /mov switch but clearly as this attempts to delete the file from source AFTER a successful copy if the file is left open in the source dir then the /mov switch wont delete it...

The command i have been trying to get to work is:

```
robocopy Source-Dir Destination-Dir *.pdf /w:20 /r:30 /mon:1 /mot:1 /log+:log.txt
```

Totally at a loss here...

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do not delete the file after upload, how would you now that any other file is a duplicate? Even if it shares the same name, (perhaps even size), it still could represent a completely different file with different content.

Obviously you will need some kind of file naming convention that all parties follow that can be used to differentiate between files.

Assuming you have an established naming convention, you have only two choices. You either rely on the users that queue up the files to remember which files have been processed, or you somehow log which files have been processed. It sounds like you want the latter option.

The process that uploads the file would write the processed file name to the log before deleting the file. The same process can also verify every new file against the log to see if it has been processed before. If it has, then simply delete it without doing anything more.

Off the top of my head, I can think of two quick ways to log the processed files.

One is to simply append each processed file name to a processed.log text file: `echo someFileName.ext >>"logPath\processed.log"`. FINDSTR can be used to check if a given name has already been processed.

Another option is to create a processed folder and log each processed file by creating an empty file with that name in the processed folder. One way to do that is `copy nul processed\someFileName.ext >nul`. IF EXIST can be used to see if a file has already been processed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Robocopy switch - assuming that Robocopy sets the Archive `A` attribute when it copies the file the first time, which it should.  This will exclude files with the A attribute set.

```
/XA:A
```